# How to ping another app running locally from Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ping

I'd like to check if a Flask app is running locally from a Rails app also running locally.

The Flask app was started with,

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:application -w 1
```

Therefore,

```
Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

How can I ping this to see if its there and running?

I've tried below without success using net/ping gem.

```
check = Net::Ping::External.new('http://0.0.0.0:5000')
check.ping?
```

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is "any ipv4 address" so you rarely want to *connect* to any address, though you often want to *listen* on any addresses. The above will also try to do ICMP and like @Casper said, you probably want HTTP or at the very least TCP.

Comment: @EnabrenTane I'm new to this - should I bind my Flask app to an address without `0.0.0.0` when running locally?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` will listen on any (ipv4) addresses the machine has. If it is your laptop at home, you probably only have a private IP address, (like `192.168.1.x` or `10.1.1.x`) so it is fine. Only other computers on your local network can reach it (unless you have port forwarding setup)

If it is an AWS instance with an EIP, that means it is "on the internet", so `0.0.0.0` would let anyone connect.

If you want *only* the same machine to talk to it, you can use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` which are more or less the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use `Net::Ping::HTTP` instead. The `External` class is used for ICMP host pings (will only check if the host is up, not a service on that host).

Check if the HTTP server is up using the HTTP protocol:

```
check = Net::Ping::HTTP.new('http://localhost:5000')
check.ping?
```

If you want to adjust the timeout to say 2 seconds instead (default is 5):

```
check = Net::Ping::HTTP.new('http://localhost:5000', nil, 2)
check.ping?
```

Comment: `ping?` returns true for `check = Net::Ping::HTTP.new('https://www.google.ca/')`, but `false` for `check = Net::Ping::HTTP.new('http://0.0.0.0:5000')` when my other app is running locally. Can you recommend anything else?

Comment: There does not exist an IP with the address `0.0.0.0`. You should use `localhost`. `0.0.0.0` is ONLY used when binding a service. It informs the service to bind to all interfaces. `0.0.0.0` can not be used for outgoing connections. So, replace `0.0.0.0` with `localhost`, and it will work like you want.